# GoogleMap Android API sample doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I try to learn Google Map API from this tutorial(https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples).
However I got error message when I run the app.
this problem provably simple issue but I'm a beginner of using android studio and Google Map API. so I have any idea to solve this....

Please give me some advice.

**error message**

> 'Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.dex.DeIndexOverFlowException:
>   method ID not in [0,0xffff]:65536

**this is what I did.**

1)download the zip file. (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples)

2)open AndroidStudio and Import project 
  from using 'Import project(Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc...)'

3)put Google MAP API key in 'gradle.properties' file.

4)run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods for dex.

You need to include multi-dex

Add these lines in build gradle

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Also in your Manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"> 
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are referring to ApiDemos and tutorials under googlemaps/android-samples

- ApiDemos using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps'`
- tutorials using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'`

The second one will deal with all play services apis instead of specific one. So you are facing the 65K limit problem.

Try using the individual api (like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps`) for all samples under googlemaps/android-samples